# 70s scary stories youth anthology. Very eerie black-and-white drawings. a ghost saves a kid from drowning

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

I'm looking for a book or books that I used to check out of my school library in the early 70s.  It was an anthology of short spooky stories for 'tweens or teens. It had several ery eerie black-and-white drawings, including one of a girl with long hair looking at her hands, which seem to be detached from her. One story involved a ghost saving a kid from drowning in a closed swimming pool. I think the ghost was named Rusty.

Comment: I am looking for this book as well! Freaky, because these are the 2 things I remember from this book!  Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to find much about it online, but I suspect that might be Ida Chittum's "Tales of Terror" (Rand McNally, 1975). It was illustrated with some very chilling black and white watercolors and several of the stories involved hauntings. Check here and see if any of these images trigger a memory: http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2008/11/tales-of-terror-1975-ida-chittum.html

Answer (score 3):

I know this is way late but hopefully it helps. I'm pretty sure this is what you have in mind.

[Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1325218.Scary_Stories_to_Tell_in_the_Dark) by Alvin Schwartz and illustrated by Bret Helquist

There are several books under that name with creepy drawings and they're all black and white pencil drawings.

Answer (score 3):

I too was searching for a book I had in my childhood.  It matched your description. It's called Horror Tales: Spirits Spells and the Unknown.  I think you are describing one of the other books in the series. Here is a [link](http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.ca/2008/12/horror-tales-spirits-spells-unknown.html).

Comment: Can you provide some descriptions of what book and what's in the link. Links tend to die and we like to have the information available for the future :)