# Book of Appalachian horror short stories, including one about a man covered in snakes, and another about a man eaten by possums

Tags: story-identification, horror, anthology-book

I remember reading this in late '70s early '80s. The stories included one about a man covered in snakes, and another about possums that ate a man buried in a shallow grave, causing his relatives to find something to eat beside possums.

Answer (score 13):

[Tales of Terror](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1423311.Tales_Of_Terror) by Ida Chittum

There's some photos here, including one page with an illustration of a lot of possums: http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2008/11/tales-of-terror-1975-ida-chittum.html

And someone else looking for the book [on Loganberry Books](http://www.loganberrybooks.com/solved-t.html) with this description:

> Cannot remember title, publisher, date for ghost story collection read
> in elementary school circa 1984-1988 that had a story about a family
> eating possum and discovers possums have eaten uncle ned's corpse and
> possibly story about a man on snipe hunt falls into river and snakes
> engulf him. May have been a child's recollection about picking rocks
> every year so the father can plow. It had a folklorish nature, maybe
> mountain folk. May have had a story about disembodied voices from a
> hole in ground or abandoned mineshaft. I think book was about 8"x10"
> and about an inch thick, was illustrated.

Comment: Also suggested as an answer here:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78694/70s-scary-stories-youth-anthology-very-eerie-black-and-white-drawings-a-ghost

Comment: a voice from a hole in the ground? If it was a welsh mine, that might be The Call of the Grave by Billy Ball, found in the anthology Monster Tales: Vampires, Werewolves & Things edited by Roger Elwood. https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/600028.Monster_Tales